# How to pick Jquery UI minDate after selection of first calendar with a set minDate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, mindate

well looking on how to create a custom math based minDate for Jquery UI .datepicker I came across that the documentation is not really there to pick a calendar date, then hove that date set the new minDate for another calendar.

but after working on this I builty this set of functions to create a date diff in jquery, php, and jquery UI .datepicker.

PLease review this and make any changes to it as needed *(I coded it in a rush at work to fix a problem)* I believe it will really help others looking for this as it took me weeks to get it done right. Because Jquery UI doesnt document the functions like this very much.

```js
jQuerREL( "#rent_from, #rent_until" ).datepicker( {
  minDate: "+0",
  dateFormat: "<?php echo transforDateFromPhpToJquery();?>",
  beforeShowDay: unavailable,
  onClose: function () {
  jQuerREL.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    update: jQuerREL(" #alert_date "),
    success: function( data ) {
      jQuerREL("#alert_date").html("");
    }
  });

  var rent_from = jQuerREL(" #rent_from ").val();
  var rent_until = jQuerREL(" #rent_until ").val();
  var todaysDate = '<?php echo $now;  ?>';
  var diffpickDate = Math.floor(( Date.parse(rent_from) - Date.parse(todaysDate) ) / 86400000);
  var dates_added = Math.floor( diffpickDate + 30);
  var mindateNew = ' "+' + dates_added + 'd"';
  console.log('Todays Date: ' + todaysDate);
  console.log('Picked Date: ' + rent_from)
  console.log('Difference in days ' + diffpickDate);
  console.log(mindateNew);
  
  jQuerREL.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?option=com_realestatemanager&task=ajax_rent_calcualete"
                    +"&bid=<?php echo $house->id; ?>&rent_from="+
                    rent_from+"&rent_until="+rent_until,
    data: { " #do " : " #1 " },
    update: jQuerREL(" #message-here "),
    success: function( data ) {
      jQuerREL("#message-here").html(data);
      jQuerREL("#calculated_price").val(data);
    }
  });

  jQuerREL("#rent_until").datepicker(
    "option", {
      changeMonth: true,
      gotoCurrent: true,
      minDate: mindateNew,
      onSelect: function(date) {
        minDate: "+30d"
        //alert(date);
      }
    }
  );
  } //end of onClose
  //jQuerREL( "#rent_until").datepicker("option", "minDate", "+30d", "changeMonths", true, "gotoCurrent", true );
  });
```

```html
<form action="https://www.thebindel.com/student-housing/16/save_rent_request?Itemid=160" method="post" name="rent_request_form">
    <div id="show_buying">
        <input name="bid[]" value="31" type="hidden">
        <input name="houseid" id="houseid" value="31" maxlength="80" type="hidden">
        <input name="calculated_price" id="calculated_price" value="0" maxlength="80" type="hidden">
        <div class="row_01">
            <div id="user_name_warning"></div>
            <input class="inputbox" id="alert_name" name="user_name" size="38" maxlength="80" placeholder="Name*" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="row_02">
            <div id="user_email_warning"></div>
            <input style="color: rgb(163, 163, 163); border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);" class="inputbox" id="alert_mail" name="user_email" size="30" maxlength="80" placeholder="Email*" type="text">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Date.prototype.toLocaleFormat = function(format) {
                var f = {Y : this.getYear() + 1900,m : this.getMonth() + 1,d : this.getDate(),
                  H : this.getHours(),M : this.getMinutes(),S : this.getSeconds()}
                for(k in f)
                    format = format.replace('%' + k, f[k] < 10 ? "0" + f[k] : f[k]);
                return format;
            };
            window.onload = function ()
            {
                var today = new Date();
                var date = today.toLocaleFormat("%m-%d-%Y");
               //fix later //first load date dug.
               // document.getElementById('rent_from').value = date;
               // document.getElementById('rent_until').value = date;
            };
        </script>
        <div class="row_05">
            <textarea name="user_mailing" cols="50" rows="8" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row_06">
            <p>Check In:</p>
            <p><input style="color: rgb(163, 163, 163); border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);" placeholder="" class="hasDatepicker" id="rent_from" name="rent_from" type="text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row_07">
            <p>Check Out:</p>
            <p><input style="color: rgb(163, 163, 163); border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);" placeholder="" class="hasDatepicker" id="rent_until" name="rent_until" type="text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="alert_date" name="alert_date"></div>
    <div id="price_1">
        <span>Price Per Month: </span>
        <span id="message-here">0</span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="message-here"> </div>
    <div class="submit-container">
        <br>
        <input value="Request to Rent " class="button wdac-button button-block btn-primary" onclick="rem_rent_request_submitbutton()" type="button">
        <br>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- PHP code needed to grab the current date and make a diff of this date with the date selected on the first calendar -->
<?php   $now = date('m-d-Y'); ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for sharing your knowledge. To be a better fit for SO, it would be good to ask the Question as if you don't know the answer (but still sharing relevant information and code), then answer it in an Answer. See [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992/215552) on Meta.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow